# ERROR: Gateway Timeout on tumblr trying to put widget in the caption. Can be fixed?

Tags: widget, runtime-error, tumblr, imacros, connection-timeout

I have a problem with Imacros and widget on tumblr. I'm trying to put a widget in the caption of some posts. Basically the widget is 4 columns 1 row. 100px width and 80 height.
Put it on my hosting, shorting url with goo.gl and put it inside a widget in the caption. This widget:

```
<iframe 
    frameborder="0" 
    height="95" 
    scrolling="no" 
    src="my widget shorten url" 
    width="435"
/iframe>
```

Bu when I run the macro got this error message inside the caption:

> ERROR: Gateway Timeout
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL http://www.example.com/widget.html:
>
> Connection timed out
>
> Your cache administrator is webmaster. Generated Fri, 04 Oct 2013
>   17:23:23 GMT by 58.62.43.131 (Mikrotik HttpProxy)

while in the imacros error message I get this:

> RuntimeError: Error loading page http://assets.tumblr.com/javascript/tiny_mce_3_4_7/themes/advanced/source_editor.htm?1097 (HTTP status code 504), line 38 (Error code: -933)

but the line in which it states an error occured is irrilevant cause trying many modifies I got the same error message always after closing html window, no matter in which line it was.

Comment: I can't see what is wrong other then connection issues. Did you check your connection ? Visit http://www.mysite.com/widget.html and check can you load it properly.

Comment: yes I can see the widget. The connection is ok. My friend also tested it and got the same mistake.

Comment: Any firewall error? Or server blocked the access to that widget ? I don't see how this has anything to do with iMacros.

Comment: I just got to understand where was the problem. It's because of the proxy. With some it works fine, while with others doesn't.